# `handle_response': Failed. Response code = 400. Response message = Bad Request. (ActiveResource::BadRequest)

Tags: asana

We are trying to fetch data from Asana through asana api using ruby script, at the time we are getting following errors.

`handle_response': Failed.  Response code = 400.  Response message = Bad Request. (ActiveResource::BadRequest)

and at the time of script(Ruby script) execute, we are getting socket error messages from asana api.

Please do the needful as soon as possible.

Comment: Any chance of getting the actual HTTP request/response so we can see what's going over the wire? Hard to say what the issue is otherwise, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you may be sending a Bad Request. Can you share the exact request (including headers and content body) to help see what the problem is? Are you using a ruby library, or is it custom? Sharing the code might help as well. (Please feel free to put REDACTED in place of any credentials/authentication tokens.)

Generally speaking, 4xx errors are client errors while 5xx errors are server errors. It's not *always* the case, but it's best to check first that the request is valid and well-formed.